# A question relating the the extension of probability from an algebra to a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory

[image][image]I was trying the prove that the following set  $\mathcal{B}$ is closed by difference i.e
$\forall A,B  \in \mathcal{B} \implies A\cap B^C \in \mathcal{B}$

$\mathcal{B}=\{A \in \mathcal{A}:P(A)=Q(A) \}$

where $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma algebra and $P$ and $Q$ are two probabilities defined on $\mathcal{A}$, supposing that $P$ and $Q$ agree on a class $C \subset \mathcal{A}$  such that $\sigma(C)=\mathcal{A}$

Now it is clear that if I choose $A,B  \in \mathcal{A}$ then $A\cap B^C \in \mathcal{A}$
But I am struggling to show that $P(A\cap B^C )=Q(A\cap B^C )$
How could I do that? Could someone give me a hint. It is probably obvious but I can't see how to do it. 
I mean  $P(A)=Q(A)$ and $P(B^C)=Q(B^C)$ follows directly from the definition of the set $\mathcal{B} $ given that $A,B \in \mathcal{B}$

Answer (score 1):

Basically $\mathcal B$ defined like this is not closed by difference.

Let $x,y,z$ be distinct elements and define $P=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{x}+\frac{1}{2}\delta_{y}$
and $Q=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{y}+\frac{1}{2}\delta_{z}$.

Here $\delta_u$ stands for the Dirac-measure defined by $\delta_u(D)=1_D(u)$.

Now let $A,B$ be
measurable sets with $x\in A\cap B^{c}$, $y\in A\cap B$ and $z\in A^{c}\cap B$.

Then $A,B\in\mathcal{B}$, but $A\cap B^{c}\notin\mathcal{B}$.

---

**edit** (after edit of question):

In $\mathcal B$ we recognize a [Dynkin system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system). Knowing that $\mathcal C$ is closed under finite intersections the Dynkin's π-λ theorem can be applied to conclude that $\mathcal B=\sigma(\mathcal C)=\mathcal A$.

Comment: But then Protter claims and then uses that $\mathcal{B}$ is closed by difference to prove the corollary 6.1. I just added the photo to the page in the question

Comment: The information about $\mathcal C$ (closed under finite intersections) is essential here and was not mentioned in your question.

Comment: I am sorry my bad. In the book Protter applies the the Monotone class theorem to prove The $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{A}=\sigma(C)$ But then in order to use it,$\mathcal{B}$ should be closed by difference and increasing limits. I still don't see why it is closed by differences in this case. Could you please tell me why? Thanks

Comment: What is stated in theorem 2.3?

Comment: I just added the screenshot

Comment: Axiom 2 of Def 2.3 is countable additivity

Comment: I am afraid that it does not help. In cor 6.1. it is mentioned that $\mathcal B$ is closed under difference with reference to th. 2.3. But there is see no verification of that. There is an [alternative route](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~sengupta/7360f09/DynkinPiLambda.pdf). Also [this](http://planetmath.org/monotoneclasstheorem) can be helpful. I must leave now. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But theorem 2.3 I believe is just used to show that $\mathcal{B} is closed under increasing limits and the fact that it is closed by difference does not require the theorem 2.3.

Comment: Final word: try to locate where in the proof it is used that $\mathcal C$ is closed under finite intersections. If you cannot find it then something must be wrong. In that case you can come back with another question.